# Posts images not showing on website after deployment

Tags: reactjs, express, apache, file-upload, cloudinary

I have a MERN stack web app that is live. Initially, I used Cloudinary for image uploads, but I decided to switch to local image uploads. I created a script to update the image references in the database, and it's functioning correctly on localhost. However, after deploying, the images are not appearing.

I attempted two methods: serving the images from the backend and referencing them with the complete URL, but it didn't work. I also tried placing the assets folder on the frontend side and referencing it directly, but the images still aren't showing, even though they were uploaded successfully (status 200) and i've tried to put the folder on the /public i've also checked that i was refering to the correct assets file that's on /var/www/html.

I've checked file permissions and the web server configuration, but everything seems to be in order. Any thoughts on this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**first way :**

`http://localhost:5000/images/posts/${localFilename}`

**seconde way :**

`"/assets/posts/${localFilename}"`